# Docker cp requires two arguments

Tags: docker, cp

I am running a docker image from [deepai/densecap](https://hub.docker.com/r/deepaiorg/densecap/) on my windows machine using docker toolbox. When i run image using docker CLI and pass the arguments for cp command as stated in below picture [image]

It says that **"docker cp" requires exactly 2 arguments"**. The various command i try to pass my image from local file system to container are:

1. docker cp C:\Users\piyush\Desktop\img1.jpg in1
2. docker cp densecap:C:\Users\piyush\Desktop\image1.jpg in1
3. docker cp C:\Users\piyush\Desktop\img1.jpg densecap:/shared/in1

I have just started using docker. Any help will be highly appreciated. I am also posting the container log:
[image]

Comment: what about `docker cp C:\Users\piyush\Desktop\img1.jpg /name_in_container.jpg`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. But i have no idea what happened next: I ran command docker cp C:\Users\piyush\Desktop\img1.jpg /densecap:in1 it executes but when i run second command as stated in above :  docker run --rm -i -v `pwd`:/shared deepaiorg/densecap it says no such file or directory.

Comment: docker uses absolute paths for mounting

Answer (score 1):

It would seem on some versions of Docker, `docker cp` does not support parameter expansion...

For example

WORKS Docker version 19.03.4-ce, build 9013bf583a

```
CTR_ID=$(docker ps -q -f name=containername)
docker cp patches $CTR_ID:/home/build
```

FAILS Docker version 19.03.4-ce, build 9013bf583a

```
BUILDHOME=/home/build
docker cp patches containeridliteral:$BUILDHOME
```

In your case, maybe the `pwd` is not expanding properly.